# When use Syntactical form in react fragment then the editor text color will be changed. How to solve this problem

Tags: reactjs, syntactic-sugar, react-fragment

Here give the problem screenshot. How to solve this problem.  have any away for solve this problem

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHUvg.png  reactFragment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Asking for a user's contact is generally not done.  All communication can and should be done in your question so other users can see how the solution was found.  Please update your question to show your code.  Please use code snippets instead of screenshots.

Comment: please elaborate your problem. read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Change your file extention to .jsx.  Happens all the time.

Comment: If i change the extension then show to error in the output..

Comment: How can i contact with you.Have you any social link?

Comment: If i change the  extention then  the problem  not solved..